# Static callback function and non-static member

Tags: c++, qt, static-methods, static-members

I actually have a code (which I can't change) needs a static function as "callback function".

When I change the function to static, I can't access "this" and my class members then. Also I can't pass "this" as parameter to function, again because I can't change the original SDK and definition files, so what can I do?

My code is in a class, one of class functions calls a function which needs a "static callback function" as parameter.
That "callback function" needs also to access "this" and other class members to process.

What can I do?
I'm using QT and VS 2012 as compiler.
Thanks

Comment: Any sensibly designed API taking a C-style callback will allow you to pass "user data" (typically a pointer) to the callback. If it does, use that to pass a pointer to the object you want to call a non-static member of. If it doesn't, burn the library and find (or write) something less hostile instead.

Comment: Simplest may be to add a static pointer to the class, which will point to instance the static callback should use. There can be just one when done like this, but it's probably ok, because if a API callback does not provide a way to pass parameters, then that API probably makes sense with just one instance only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static function is in common with a global function, u can't image that u can use "this" in a global function, and not to mention class members...
The only difference is a static function has a "namespace" as known as the calss name.
So, no matter what are you using or which compliler it is, you cannot use "this" or class members in a static function, it's just language features.
And you should modify your code as Mike says.

Answer (score 0):

If you use modern versions of C++ (11 or older) you may use [`std::bind`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/). Or use `boost:bind`.